# Animated table-view cell when the user picks up with his finger (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, swift3

I'm trying to make this animation [image]

so i want that when the user picks up with his finger the cell get smaller and then when it stops pressing come back on the original size, important is that i'm not using a custom cell but the default UITableViewCell, here is my code with whom i tried to do the animation (after watching old question and tutorial)

```
 var originalCellSize: CGRect!  

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("I'm Highlighted at \(indexPath.section)")


        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)  else {
            return
        }

        originalCellSize = cell.frame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x + 20, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.width - 40, height: cell.frame.height)
        })
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
            return
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.originalCellSize.origin.y, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 180)
        })

        originalCellSize = .zero
    }
```

i don't know why but something is wrong and the animation do not work, can someone help me (it also happens that after pushing on the cell this changes position in a definitive way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't manipulate `UITableViewCell`'s frame directly. 
Use it's `transform` property. 
Likewise:

Scale down the cell upon highlight / selection.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Scale back to normal:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Don't forget to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before the animation block and inside (right after assigning the CGAffineTransform).

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the problem in a different way. You can resize a view inside the Table view cell.

Like you can keep a view with white color and cell background as grey color. In highlight delegate method, you can change the frame of UIView inside the cell and on unhighlight method, you can resize to back to cell size.

Answer (score 0):

WhenEver You want to change layout of cell you must need to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set flag that cell should change size.
2. Add flag check for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
3. On highlighting use:

   `table.beginUpdates()`

   `table.reloadRowsAt(...)`

   `table.endUpdates()`

Should work just fine.

I'm not sure you can just change frame of the cell. So you can also try try to change cell's content view size. Or your custom view frame itself.